# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json ,added Jakson dependency still issue persisit

Tags: json, web-services, rest, maven, pom.xml

I am creating restful webservice ,I am trying to get json response but getting Message writer not found exception.In Jersey site it was mentioned to use Jakson dependency for application/JSON so i used it still getting the same error. For response type application/xml it is working fine.
These are dependency available in POM ,still getting Message writer not found exception.Can anyone please help -

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
public class UserServiceTest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
 protected Application configure(){
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig=new ResourceConfig(UserService.class);
     return resourceConfig;
 }
@Test
public void test(){
    String output=target("/users/test").request().get(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);
    //assertEquals("abc",output);
    Assert.assertEquals("abc",output);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to register the `JacksonFeature` with your application. This is only required pre-2.9

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the comment .pls suggest  how to do that? i used jettison .it gave same error

Comment: Show your app configuration, whether it's web.xml or Java config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Jersey 2.9, you need to register the `JacksonFeature` (where after, it is automatically registered). In your case just register it with the `ResourceConfig`

```
resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class)
```

The `ResourceConfig` is only for configuring the server side. For the client side, you can register the feature like

```
@Override
public void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
    config.register(JacksonFeature.class)l
}
```

in your `JerseyTest`.